# Resize android ImageView for landscape and portrait

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to figure out how I can load a portrait or landscape image in android ImageView without stretching the image to full screen.

For example, a landscape image when viewed in portrait should not stretch to fullscreen but centered with black stripe on top and bottom to compensate empty space.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: use layout-port and layout-land folders inside res folder.

Answer (score 2):

set the height and width of the imageview to match_parent  ,  whitout using any scaleType

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />
```

it will be automatically fit for portrait and landscape

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that effect you need to use `scaleType` attribute and a black background.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/your_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:background="#000000"/>
```

Then you need to set the image resource.

Via xml:

```
android:src="@drawable/your_image_drawable"
```

Via code:

```
yourImageViewReference.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image_drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

in the XML i set `android:scaleType="fitXY"`
Now both my portrait and landscape images takes the same space.